# How to fix net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

Tags: angular, typescript, rest

I'm trying to learn Angular and Typescript to implement UI for my project. When I'm trying to pass 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' : '*' in the header(for solving CORS error). I have the following error message:

```
OPTIONS http://192.168.100.31:9000/try net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
```

The method which invokes back-end endpoint:

```
getTry(){    
let headers = new HttpHeaders().set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");    
const options = {headers};    
return this.http.get(this.apiUrl, options)    
  .map((res: HttpResponse<any>)  => res.body)    
  .subscribe( data => {    
    console.log(data);    
    this.data = data;    
  })
```

}

If I use "return this.http.get(this.apiUrl)" I have the CORS error, If i try to pass the options too, I get the 404 error.

I'm really a beginner with front-end stuff so maybe I missed something.
Any idea on how to solve this?

Comment: you have [cors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) the other way around. its the server job to allow requests so you do that from your backend not while sending request

Comment: you were right, thanks for the advice

Comment: hi, @MiklósTakács how did you solve this? would you please share? I am also getting the same error.

Comment: hi @nilimaakter, as previous commenter suggested I allowed it in the backend. In my case it was a Play framework project in Scala so I had to edit the application.conf file